# 'ls' taking a long time to list 20 subdirectories

Tags: linux, centos5, unix-shell, ls, command-line-interface

I have a directory (my_dir) which has 20 sub directories.  Every time I run 'ls' or try to autocomplete a file name in this directory my IO usage goes to 100% and it takes very long time (10 mins) to list 20 sub directories.

Here is some background for it.
Some time ago, I created millions of small files in this directory (By mistake).  Then I deleted those small files (all of them).  But now I am seeing this problem.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Results fox `fsck /dev/hda..`? (Replace the device with your hard drive.)

Answer (score 4):

Move everything in the directory in to another directory. Remove the original directory. Recreate the original directory. Move everything back.

You are using a filesystem that can't shrink directories.

There's always [`e2fsck -D`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ext3#Using_Directory_Indexing) which will optimize all directories on the filesystem.

Comment: +1 - Learn something new every day..